# I want to fetch next code value from Database when my form load into textfield i am using this code

Tags: php

```
<?php <br>
include("connection.php"); <br>
$insert="select maxcode(ClassID)+1 from class"; 
$result=mysqli_query($con,$insert); 

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
?> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cid" value="<?php echo $row['ClassID'];?>"> 

<?php 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of a `maxcode()` function in MYSQL, did you mean `MAX()`.

Use an alias for the selected column when using functions on a column or the column gets a name like `max(ClassID)+1`

So then you can use the alias name in the `$row['ClassID']`

```
<?php <br>
include("connection.php"); <br>
$insert="select max(ClassID)+1 as  ClassID from class"; 
//       change ^^^ and alias here ^^^^^^^^^^  
$result=mysqli_query($con,$insert); 

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
?> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cid" value="<?php echo $row['ClassID'];?>"> 

<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in E:\Xampp\htdocs\Elixir\class.php on line 6:     i get this error after running above code

Comment: Then can you add the `connection.php` script to your question please so I can see it

Comment: Ahh. I dont know of a `maxcode()` function I assume you ment `max()` see if that change helps